# Mysql select totals for each category by day

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.

`categories` table

> id | number

`items` table

> id | number | cat_id

`orders` table

> id | item_id | date_time

I'm trying to select total order's per day for each category that has at least one order during the time period in the query.

Desired results:

```
Date        Category Total
2013-12-01  001      6
2013-12-01  002      0
2013-12-01  003      1
2013-12-02  001      14
2013-12-02  002      2
2013-12-02  003      0
2013-12-03  001      11
2013-12-03  002      4
2013-12-03  003      4
```

I've tried a lot of ways but nothing worked. I found this http://www.richnetapps.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/ and added a calendar table accordingly but that didn't work either.

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, categories.number, count(orders.id) 
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN items on categories.id = items.cat_id
LEFT JOIN orders on items.id = order.item_id
RIGHT JOIN calendar ON DATE(orders.order_date) = calendar.datefield
WHERE calendar.datefield BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-06'
GROUP BY DATE, categories.number asc
```

Thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I've tried everything in my limited mysql arsenal.

Comment: Please give one or more examples of what you have tried.

Comment: What output are you getting from the query you posted? A quick look makes me think you would be getting the desired result; it appears correct. Please post a small sample of what it returns.

Comment: I get only the categories that have an order that day

Comment: Please post a small data sample from each table or better, setup a sample over at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: `DATE       number   IFNULL( count(order.id), 0 )
2013-11-01  3        1
2013-11-02  3        1
2013-11-03  1        1
2013-11-03  3        3
2013-11-04  1        1
2013-11-04  3        2
2013-11-05  1        3
2013-11-05  3        3
2013-11-06  1        1
2013-11-06  2        1
2013-11-06  3        3`

Comment: 1. What is `tr.trans_date`? There is no table `tr` here. You have dates in `orders` table so you don't need anything else. There is no `categories.number` column and actually your query is dealing with some different tables/columns you haven't shown. Why can't you show the actual tables and actual query? Otherwise there is no way to find what's wrong... 2. Don't use in-built functions (DATE) as alias.

Comment: Sorry about the delay I'm not so good at formatting in stackoverflow

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Okay I'll try to do that now

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f809a/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:** You can do it this way

```
SELECT d.date, d.cat_id, COALESCE(o.total, 0) total
  FROM
(
  SELECT c.date, i.cat_id
    FROM calendar c CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT i.cat_id
      FROM orders o JOIN items i
        ON o.item_id = i.id
     WHERE o.order_date >= '2013-11-01'
       AND o.order_date < '2013-11-07'
  ) i
   WHERE c.date BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-06'
) d LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT DATE(o.order_date) date, i.cat_id, COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) total
    FROM orders o JOIN items i
        ON o.item_id = i.id
     WHERE o.order_date >= '2013-11-01'
       AND o.order_date < '2013-11-07'
   GROUP BY DATE(o.order_date), i.cat_id
) o
     ON d.date = o.date
    AND d.cat_id = o.cat_id
 ORDER BY d.date, d.cat_id
```

Some explanation:

1. *In a subquery with an alias `d` we create all possible combinations of all dates from calendar and category ids from orders for that period of time.*
2. *In a subquery with an alias `o` with calculate total number of orders per date and category id in the time period of interest.*
3. *Then in the outer select we use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to ensure that all date - category id combinations that we produced on the step 1 are present in the final resultset.*

Output:

```
+------------+--------+-------+
| date       | cat_id | total |
+------------+--------+-------+
| 2013-11-01 |      1 |     0 |
| 2013-11-01 |      2 |     0 |
| 2013-11-01 |      3 |     1 |
| 2013-11-02 |      1 |     0 |
| 2013-11-02 |      2 |     0 |
| 2013-11-02 |      3 |     1 |
| 2013-11-03 |      1 |     1 |
| 2013-11-03 |      2 |     0 |
| 2013-11-03 |      3 |     3 |
| 2013-11-04 |      1 |     1 |
| 2013-11-04 |      2 |     0 |
| 2013-11-04 |      3 |     2 |
| 2013-11-05 |      1 |     3 |
| 2013-11-05 |      2 |     0 |
| 2013-11-05 |      3 |     3 |
| 2013-11-06 |      1 |     1 |
| 2013-11-06 |      2 |     1 |
| 2013-11-06 |      3 |     3 |
+------------+--------+-------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4278a/1)** demo

Comment: This one doesn't give me zeros.

Comment: Do you want each category to be listed for each day?

Comment: Yes, each category that has at least one order in time period.

Comment: Now I have to study this query so I know what I'm doing and not just be a copy cat

Comment: You're quite welcome ;) See updated answer for a short explanation

Comment: Thanks again! Just wondering why for `order_date` you went with  `>= '2013-11-01'` and `< '2013-11-07'` and for `calendar_date` you used `BETWEEN`

Comment: It's because `calendar.date` doesn't have time component.